# how to cast arraylist to a class

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am working on a shopping cart, and am getting an exception that an `ArrayList` cannot be cast to a `ShoppingCart`. How do I cast an `ArrayList` to this class?

### Code

```
ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
shoppingCart = (ShoppingCart) session.getAttribute("shoppingCart");
if(shoppingCart == null){
    shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
}
```

I got this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to business.ShoppingCart
```

which points to

```
shoppingCart = (ShoppingCart) session.getAttribute("shoppingCart");
```

Comment: The error is clear, did you store an ArrayList of ShoppingCart in the session ?

Comment: dont think so, could u pls give me a solution @Berger

Comment: Can you give more explanation. If possible, how you get this session parameter

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast an `ArrayList` to a class, other than `Object`, or an interface other than `List` or `Collection`.

The best you can do is **convert** the `ArrayList` into your `ShoppingCart` class somehow, like:

```
ShoppingCart cart = null;
Object cart_object  = session.getAttribute("shoppingCart");
if (cart_object instanceof ArrayList) {
    ArrayList cart_list = (ArrayList) cart_object;
    cart = new ShoppingCart(cart_list);
}
```

Alternately, you could build a new shopping cart, and add the contents of the list to it:

```
ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
Object cart_object  = session.getAttribute("shoppingCart");
if (cart_object instanceof ArrayList) {
    ArrayList cart_list = (ArrayList) cart_object;
    for(Object item : cart_list) {
        cart.add(item);
    }
}
```

But exactly how, or what you need to do, depends on the implementation details of your `ShoppingCart` class.

Comment: Object objShoppingCart = session.getAttribute("shoppingCart");
            if(objShoppingCart != null){
                shoppingCart = (ShoppingCart) objShoppingCart;
            } i tried this and still got the same error @AJNeufeld

Comment: No, that is still casting an `ArrayList`, stored in an `Object` variable, to a `ShoppingCart`, which is not possible.  You need to construct your shopping cart object using the list, or store the shopping cart as a shopping cart.

Comment: i appreciate your answers, but could pls show me a working code that adds more that one item to a shopping cart. thanks @AJNeufeld

Comment: The above code would call `add` for each item in the `ArrayList`.  Without more details about the interface to the `ShoppingCart`, the contents of the session's `shoppingCart` attribute, and the platform, I don't think we can provide anything useful for your issue.  But that needs be posted as a new question.  The question _"how to cast ArrayList to a class"_ has been answered: you can't.